# How should we distinguish between series and individual books?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions, such as [redwall] could apply to both the book and the series. How should we distinguish between questions about the book, but not the series as a whole?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do the same thing we do with authors. A tag for the series, and a tag for specific books. If your question is about the series as a whole, use the series tag. If your question is about a specific book, use both the series tag and book tag.

In the case where the names overlap, you can use something like [redwall-series](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redwall-series) for the series, and reserve [redwall](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redwall) for the book itself. That makes it clear which is which, though we might have to do the occasional [redwall](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redwall) -> [redwall-series](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redwall-series) edit to fix mistakes. I've made the change to the two questions here.

Using LotR:

- Have a [j-r-r-tolkien](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) tag for all of Tolkien's works.
- Have a [lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) tag for all series questions.

Then, use the following if applicable:

- Have a [fellowship-of-the-ring](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fellowship-of-the-ring) tag for just the first book.
- Have a [the-two-towers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-two-towers) tag for just the second book.
- Have a [return-of-the-king](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-king) tag for just the third book.

Comment: But, Redwall is also the title of the first book?

Comment: @Benjamin In that case, using something like [tag:redwall-series] for just the series and [tag:redwall] for the first book works. The principle is the same.

Comment: OMG. If we can establish this kind of system all the way from private beta, Literature's tagging system will be ***way*** better than SFF's. +100 if I could.

Comment: @Randal'Thor This sounds a lot like the M&TV policy :P

Comment: @Catija Except that M&TV doesn't use author tags in this way.

Comment: @Randal'Thor *"If we can establish this kind of system all the way from private beta, Literature's tagging system will be way better than SFF's"* - You realize this now? ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor only if the tag editing is kept up diligently ;)

Comment: @Helmar which is why it's best to start now :)

Comment: @fi12 [I know](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/81/keeping-tags-clean-from-the-start)